# How to use Microsoft Edge in mac?

Tags: browser, website, microsoft-edge

Microsoft announced a new web browser in Windows 10 named **Edge**.

While there is no download option for Mac OS X (like Internet Explorer 5+), how can I use it and test my websites with it?

I know about Virtualbox, Wine and finally Bootcamp but isn't there an easier and more official way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that Edge is based on Chromium, the Beta and Dev Channels have builds of **Microsoft Edge for Mac OS**. The installer can be downloaded from [Microsoft Edge Insider Channels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=win7).

Answer (score 16):

There is no version of Microsoft Edge that runs natively on Mac OS X.

However, we do have some options in the works to help Mac users test their sites in MS Edge.

1. We provide pre-configured Windows 10 VMs that are ready to run and test Microsoft Edge. They are available at: http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/. You can read the announcement [here](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/17/windows-10-virtual-machines-now-available-on-microsoft-edge-dev/).
2. We have a cloud streaming version (previously "RemoteIE") that we are going to upgrade to Microsoft Edge. This will take us a bit longer due to Azure changes needed but will be available at http://remote.modern.ie.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no standalone app that can be downloaded, it was coded within Windows 10.

After all, it is not an exe file

Comment: if there is no exe file, wine is not an option anymore.

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri - There is an executable.  WINE still isn't an option but for entirely different reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound and whats that reason ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Safari and navigate to **Safari > Preferences** from the menu bar.
2. Click on the **Advanced** tab.
3. Check the **"Show Develop menu in menu bar"** setting, then close the Preferences window.
4. The **Develop** **menu** should now show in your menu bar.
5. Go to **Develop > User Agent**.
6. Here, you have to option to choose different browser options like ***Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, 10*** and ***11***. You can also choose ***Firefox*** and ***Chrome*** as the **User Agent**.

*Source*: [How to view websites on your Mac that require Internet Explorer (or a PC)](https://www.imore.com/how-view-websites-your-mac-require-internet-explorer-or-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now directly provide [VM images](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for testing of IE8 to Edge for various VM environments (e.g. VirtualBox, VmWare etc). A snag is that they expire after 90days but they suggest you snapshot once you've installed the image and then just roll it back when it expires.